# canjs using jquery and mustache

Tags: jquery, mustache, canjs

How to read a DIV id from a .mustache file using jQuery?

e.g. 
asdf.mustache

```
<div class="draggable"> 
    <p>drag this here</p>
</div>
```

adminControl.js

```
define(['jQuery', 'can', 'ctbConfig','labelsConfig'], function(jQuery, can,     ctbConfig,labelsConfig) {
$(".draggable").draggable();
}
```

Here $(".draggable").draggable(); is not working.

Comment: Is the template rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements in an rendered template using jQuery `filter()`

```
var template = '<div class="draggable"> <p>drag this here</p></div>';
var html = Mustache.render(template, {});
// Use filter to get the element .draggable
$(html).filter('.draggable').draggable();
```

I don't think you will be able to call .draggable(); on the element until it is rendered to the DOM.

Read more about `filter()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).